# memory-efficient & clean set() in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of unique colors (rgba values) in an image. Here are my attempts:

```
# 1 - too ugly and clunky
all_colors = []
for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
                color = pix[i, j]
                if color not in all_colors:
                        all_colors.append(color)
```

OR

```
# 2 - not memory-efficient, as it adds the whole list into memory
all_colors = list(set([pix[i, j] for i in range(width) for j in range(height)]))
```

Edit: here is the setup:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("../Camouflage.png")
pix = img.load()
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `as it adds the whole list into memory` both options do that. Or you mean something else?

Comment: @Marc Looks like they mean "the whole list of all pixels", not just the list of *different* colors.

Comment: Quite possibly there's a way without looping yourself, but we can't tell because you're keeping it secret what `pix` is and not giving us a chance to test.

Comment: @Manuel, just updated to show what `pix` is. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are any of the downvoters going to bother explaining what's wrong with my question?

Comment: The downvotes from before your latest edits were probably because the code was incomplete, lacking context. On Code Review, we require more than just snippets. Feel free to refer to [Simon's guide on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/52915).

Comment: Why do you want the code to be more memory efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about simply this?

```
all_colors = set(img.getdata())
```

Or let Pillow do the hard work:

```
all_colors = [color for _, color in img.getcolors()]
```

Benchmark results along with the set comprehension solution on a test image of mine (since you didn't provide any):

```
113 ms  set_comp
 68 ms  set_getdata
  1 ms  getcolors

115 ms  set_comp
 65 ms  set_getdata
  1 ms  getcolors

106 ms  set_comp
 62 ms  set_getdata
  1 ms  getcolors
```

With [`img.getdata()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) you get a "sequence-like object" that seems light-weight:

```
>>> img.getdata()
<ImagingCore object at 0x7f0ebd0f1e50>

>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(img.getdata())
32
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat
from PIL import Image

def set_comp(img):
    pix = img.load()
    width, height = img.size
    return {pix[i,j] for i in range(width) for j in range(height)}

def set_getdata(img):
    return set(img.getdata())

def getcolors(img):
    return [color for _, color in img.getcolors()]

funcs = set_comp, set_getdata, getcolors

def main():
    img = Image.open("test.png")
    for _ in range(3):
        for func in funcs:
            t = min(repeat(lambda: func(img), number=1))
            print('%3d ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
        print()

main()
```

Comment: hmmm I think part of its speed comes from the fact that you don't need to `img.load()` the whole image. but, I'll need to do that eventually to iterate over the pixels and change them if they're not black.

Comment: @tommy2111111111 Have a look at `getdata`'s source code (it's linked to in the documentation), the first thing it does is `self.load()`. Also, see my update, new solution using `getcolors`.

Comment: thank you, `getcolors` works great. would it still be the best/fastest solution if I still needed to iterate over all the pixels anyways like this? https://pastebin.com/UnAR6kzv

Comment: @tommy2111111111 I don't see what getting the colors has to do with that. Anyway, for efficient manipulation there might be other Pillow methods or you could use NumPy on the image data.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't necessary to pass a `list` to `set()`. Use a generator expression:

```
all_colors = set(pix[i,j] for i in range(width) for j in range(height))
```

or, use a set comprehension:

```
all_colors = {pix[i,j] for i in range(width) for j in range(height)}
```

I timed them by building sets of 1_000_000 items. On average, the set comprehension was a < 10ms faster and they were within 1 std dev of each other.

Comment: They already do. The thing you're doing which they're not is the *generator*. Btw less efficient than using a set comprehension.

Comment: @Manuel, how so? Generators are far more memory efficient that comprehensions since they are lazy iterators. There's no real difference in terms of computational complexity, it is exactly the same.

Comment: @pavel No, feeding the generator to `set` completely eliminates that memory efficiency. The complexity class is the same, yes, but all the back-and-forth between generator and `set` does make it slower.

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @pavel [small benchmark](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv@Yq5lCRSpLUXEXrsF/QoIhW2GjBpSFeoiN9eEwPiHBb2zbA7/sm3yTV7H9Z1DJMFG0uGYayfAiOQp4GF6NFCDnHczcwqDO5Kqq6qSmtsUFdSdNE7CkTJmVgtGKeABcZh0LLMxuufviM9CZHAOYF8s9GHbzZhSrjLexLHF9Y4lTspKtGXcA97odDmLr@oD8axksV2N0oU4BKUzWzodf0A)